# Display HTML tag characters as plain text

Tags: html, css

How do I display

```
<b> > Greater than <b>
<b> < Less Than <b>
<b> <> Not Equal to <b>
```

In the above code The greater than sign does not show up in bold. Same goes for the others

Comment: Have a look at the [HTML entities](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp)

Comment: Possibly the font you're using doesn't have those characters in bold?

Comment: Someone else commented, but for some reason deleted their comment.  They are bold, the difference is just really minute at small sizes.  If you make the font really big the difference is apparent.  http://jsfiddle.net/vJ4eG/

Comment: This is *not* a duplicate. The question is about bolding.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use [ampersand html character codes](http://rabbit.eng.miami.edu/info/htmlchars.html)

Note the bolded < > signs in the first set.

```html
<b> &gt; Greater than </b>
<b> &lt; Less Than </b>
<b> &lt;&gt; Not Equal to </b>


<p> 
    &gt; Greater than 
    &lt; Less Than 
    &lt;&gt; Not Equal to 
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. Marked as the answer

Comment: Exactly how did it help? Although such escaping is recommended, for good reasons, it has nothing to do with the question about bolding.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - The symbols are bolded. Exactly what is your issue with this answer and how do you perceive this as not working?

Comment: Using the escapes does not change the rendering a bit,

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - The question reads "Display HTML tag characters as plain text". This addresses that issue. Clearly it helped the OP based on their comment, perhaps this was a trivial example of something else they were doing (maybe the contents come from a script). Either way, the symbols are bolded.

Comment: The question title differs from the question body. In such cases, it is fair to assume that the body has the real question.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela - It is still an assumption. This answer addresses both the body and the title. The symbols are bolded, and the characters are plain text.

Comment: This answer does not address the question in the body at all, and it is based on an assumption about the real problem. And escaping “>” is never necessary, escaping “<” is necessary in certain conditions only, and *not* in the case presented.

Comment: Does not answer the question and does not even work.

Comment: @TylerDurden - It answers the question, although to be fair it was missing the `</b>` (because the OP was at the time). I fixed it up a little bit, you can now see it working in the inline demo.

Answer (score 2):

The characters “<” and “>” do appear in bold, they are just not as bold as you would expect. You can see this by trying with different font faces and sizes. E.g., in typical 12pt size Arial, they differ from non-bold characters visibly when you put them side by side.

Font designers may decide to avoid thick strokes in bold versions of special characters, since bolding is primarily meant for letters. Some special characters would look too odd if designed too bold.

Note that this has absolutely nothing to do with the representation of “<” and “>” as `&lt;` and `&gt;` in HTML source. It is generally recommended to escape “<”, but it is technically not necessary here (and “>” never needs to be escaped, though many people escape it for symmetry).

Comment: How does this address the issue of displaying tags as plain text? The OP may be placing the markup from script.

Comment: This answers the question asked. The title is misleading, and *if* it were the real question, *then* the question should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

The greater than and less than signs are special characters in HTML.  You need to write them as `&gt;` for greater than and `&lt;` for less than.

You'll notice that even then, the `>` and `<` signs aren't very bold.  The difference becomes more pronounced as the font size increases.  The font just doesn't add a whole lot of bolding to these characters.

Answer (score 1):

Use `&gt;` and `&lt;` for greater and less than.

In addition, while the `<b>` tag is still part of the HTML spec, `<strong>` is much more semantic. Why do you ask? It is because bold is a style, whereas strong just says that this should be noticed, and leaves the styling out of it. Formatting is for CSS, defining structure and contents is a job for HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

"`&#60;`" or "`&gt;`" for  "<"

use "`&#62;`" or "`&gt;`" for ">"

Refer this for more :- http://www.ascii-code.com/

Answer (score -1):

In the old days, you used to be able to write  and then whatever you wrote wouldn't be interpreted as HTML. I'm not sure if it still works, but it may be worth a shot.

Comment: Where is the answer in your post???

Comment: It would be <pre><h1><!--any tags go here---!></h1></pre>