# Text not showing after < in page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, grails

I have a an example text as below -

```html
< p>pppp </ p>SP717171 MISSEDAb, S<Dtest 123333
```

While rendering the above text in a div, the contents after `S<` is removed. On inspecting it, the browser seems to treat it as a tag but it is an invalid HTML tag. How do I preserve such content and only treat valid HTML tags as it is?

For example in this case I want `< p>pppp </ p>` to display as `pppp` and also the contents after `S<` should be shown.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Display HTML tag characters as plain text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18904193/display-html-tag-characters-as-plain-text)

Comment: @Jejun No it doesn't friend

Answer (score 1):

To output `<` and `>` characters in HTML, and prevent them being interpreted as parts of an HTML tag you need to HTML-encode them. In this case using `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively:

```html
<p>pppp</p>SP717171 MISSEDAb, S&lt;Dtest 123333
```

Comment: I am not setting this text manually and getting it from database, so is there a way to identify which < to convert to &lt; and similar for > ?

Comment: Not really, as any HTML parser would have the same result as you see in your browser - all content between `<` and `>` is interpreted as HTML, whether it's valid or not. You need to sanitise/HTML encode the input before it's saved in the database. Also be ***very*** careful inserting HTML in to your database as you're leaving a big open door for XSS attacks.